# How to merge two collections in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I get the data from `$request` object the I convert it into collection:

```
foreach ($request->get('dates') as $date) {
    $this->inputDates->push([
        "starttime" => $this->convert($date['starttime']),
        "endtime" => $this->convert($date['endtime'])
    ]);
}
```

The I fetch data from database table:

```
$this->existDates = $this->get($this->user->getId())->map(fn($model) => $model->only(['starttime', 'endtime']));
```

After all I try to merge two collectons:

```
$this->allDates = $this->existDates->merge($this->inputDates);
```

As result I got this error:

> { "message": "Call to a member function getKey() on array", "exception": "Error", "file": "C:\xampp\htdocs\app\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection.php", "line": 343, "trace":

I expect to get merged collection with two fields: starttime, endtime. Then reduce it into flat array: `[date1, date2, date3...]` and sort it.

Comment: Try converting to a base collection first like e.g `collect($this->existDates->all())->merge`

Comment: Is it properly way or I do something wrong?

Comment: The problem is that the eloquent collection is an extension of the normal Laravel collections and does work on the model identifiers (to ensure unique rows in the collection probably), since you did `only(['starttime', 'endtime'])` those keys were lost so the collection no longer was able to use them. One way around this is what I suggested above and the other way would probably be to `only(['id','starttime', 'endtime'])` I guess there might be other ways too. Check https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-collections for more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can merge by doing array and object conversions:
Push to array:

```
$this->inputDates = (object) array_push((array) $this->inputDates, array(
    "starttime" => $this->convert($date['starttime']),
    "endtime" => $this->convert($date['endtime'])
));
```

Merge arrays:

```
$this->allDates = (object) array_merge($this->existDates->toArray(), $this->inputDates->toArray());
```